# Google protobuf Boolvalue is generating FieldCodec<bool> type bool file

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers

I am using Google.protobuf.BoolValue type in my .proto file, but when I compile the proto file, I see the variable type as FieldCodec in autogenerated field, instead of BoolValue type of well known types.

Because of this, when I use this variable in my c# file, I can use it as bool type and it is accepting values without error. But when assigning the value using **new BoolValue{}**, Im getting error.

this is my proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

option csharp_namespace = "cSharpSample";

message StudentMessage {
  string Name = 1;
  google.protobuf.BoolValue IsGood = 2; 
  bool Isbool = 3;
}
```

Autogenerated file:

```
/// <summary>Field number for the "IsGood" field.</summary>
public const int IsGoodFieldNumber = 2;
private static readonly pb::FieldCodec<bool?> _single_isGood_codec =   pb::FieldCodec.ForStructWrapper<bool>(18);
private bool? isGood_;
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("protoc", null)]
public bool? IsGood {
   get { return isGood_; }
   set {
     isGood_ = value;
   }
}
```

in program.cs file:

```
StudentMessage msg = new StudentMessage(); 
msg.Isbool = true;
msg.IsGood= new BoolValue { Value = true };
```

I get this error:
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.BoolValue' to 'bool?'

The Variable **IsGood** should work like BoolValue, but it is working like bool type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated tooling special-cases this scenario, and uses `bool?` instead of the wrapper message type. This provided both a more idiomatic .NET API (since the semantics of `BoolValue` and `bool?` are similar), and avoids some allocations. So : just use the `bool?` and forget about `BoolValue` entirely!

`FieldCodec` here is `static` and is just part of the machinery; you don't need to interact with that at all.

Comment: got it. Since I defined the variable as **BoolValue** in proto file, I treated it as BoolValue in my cs file, but on checking the autogenerated file, it used **bool?**. But as you said both behaves the same way, then no problem.

Comment: @Monika the entire point of BoolValue is to be able to represent true, false or no-value; that's exactly what `bool?` represents - so yes they're exactly interchangeable